# Fuchsia won't compile: Image Aseembly Failed

Tags: compiler-errors, fuchsia

I've been following the steps on Fuchsia.dev for configuring a build environment running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.  I have worked through a few issues to this point but have hit a wall on this last issue and could use some insight/help.  Here is the error I get no matter what PRODUCT.BOARD combo I try and build:

Image Assembly Failed
1.  ./host_x64/zbi exited with status: exit status: 1

I get a failure with each of these actions :

```
ACTION //build/images/zedboot:zedboot_image_assembler(//build/toolchain/fuchsia:x64)

ACTION //build/images/fuchsia:fuchsia_image_assembler(//build/toolchain/fuchsia:x64)

ACTION //build/images/fuchsia:fuchsia_prime_assembly_image_assembler(//build/toolchain/fuchsia:x64)
```

A little more from the log that may be helpful:

```
------ GIT QUICK INFO ------
$ git status
HEAD detached at ecc8f1f181d
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git rev-parse JIRI_HEAD
ecc8f1f181d320993095468faca6d1a6ffaf8cab

------ CONTENTS OF args.gn ------
$ cat /home/john/fuchsia/out/default/args.gn

import("//boards/qemu-x64.gni")
import("//products/core.gni")
build_info_board = "qemu-x64"
build_info_product = "core"
enable_rbe = false
is_debug = true
use_goma = false
base_package_labels += []
cache_package_labels += []
host_labels += []
universe_package_labels += [ "//examples/hello_world" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fix for this issue was submitted [here](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/04035164f65eeb5824a56d74265f987c8937d9cd), which came shortly after the commit where your `JIRI_HEAD` is pointing.

Running `jiri update` and building again should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.